# How to delete keys an a Array of Docs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a simple way to only return a few keys in my case for example i want to only return headername, field and type if it exists. I know i can delete keys via

```
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  delete obj[i]['type']
  delete obj[i]['hide']
  delete obj[i]['position']
}
```

which would mean i would have to loop over all docs in array and delete the keys but not sure if there is a simpler faster way to achieve the same. In my case this doc will never be huge as it only stores column definitions for export of data

```
[   {
             "headerName": "assessed_combined_value",
             "field": "assessed_combined_value",
             "hide": false,
             "position": 8,
             "type": "money"
        },
        {
             "headerName": "assessee1",
             "field": "assessee1",
             "hide": false,
             "position": 1
        },
        {
             "headerName": "assessee2",
             "field": "assessee2",
             "hide": false,
             "position": 2
        },
        {
             "headerName": "bathrooms",
             "field": "bathrooms",
             "hide": false,
             "position": 5
        }
        ]
```

Comment: how is the data coming to you? If you control the query to the db (if there is a db) you can not select the field

Answer (score 3):

You can use destructuring

```js
let data = [{"headerName": "assessed_combined_value","field": "assessed_combined_value","hide": false,"position": 8,"type": "money"},{"headerName": "assessee1","field": "assessee1","hide": false,"position": 1},{"headerName": "assessee2","field": "assessee2","hide": false,"position": 2},{"headerName": "bathrooms","field": "bathrooms","hide": false,"position": 5}]

let final = data.map(({field, headerName}) => ({headerName, field}))

console.log(final)
```

If the case is vice-versa you want to leave only some of properties behind and want to select all other properties you can use `spread syntax` i.e if you want to leave out only `field` key

```
let final = data.map(({field, ...rest}) => rest)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spread operator combining with the previously posted answer to show only those fields which are present in the currently iterated object.

```js
let info = [{
    "headerName": "assessed_combined_value",
    "field": "assessed_combined_value",
    "hide": false,
    "position": 8,
    "type": "money"
},
{
    "headerName": "assessee1",
    "field": "assessee1",
    "hide": false,
    "position": 1
},
{
    "headerName": "assessee2",
    "field": "assessee2",
    "hide": false,
    "position": 2
},
{
    "headerName": "bathrooms",
    "field": "bathrooms",
    "hide": false,
    "position": 5
}]

const result = info.map(({field, headerName, type}) => ({
    ...(headerName && {"headerName": headerName}),
    ...(field && {"field": field}),
    ...(type && {"type": type})
}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: So is there a significant benefit by using one vs the other specially if the Docs and Arrays are not to big like 10 docs in array and maybe 20 - 40 keys in a doc.

Comment: You won't get `{type: undefined}` properties if you use my example. Only in those cases, when the original object had the `type` property with a value.